# Assignment operator to assign expressions separated by comma in C++98 to a variable does not assign

Tags: android, c++, variable-assignment, increment, c++98

Using Android Marshmallow CppDroid app, which uses C++98 but supports some C++11.

I'm following a C++ course, and I'm confused by the output of the following:

```
int a=0, b=0, c=0;
std::cout << "a:" << a << '\n' << "b:" << b << '\n' << "c:" << c << '\n';
// output is 
// a:0
// b:0
// c:0
a = b++, c++
std::cout << "a:" << a << '\n' << "b:" << b << '\n' << "c:" << c << '\n';
// Output is 
// a:0
// b:1
// c:1
```

I'm confused as to why the assignment operator did not assign the value of `c++` to `a`.

**EDIT**

As noted by the comment by @molbdnilo, this is not a matter of precedence, but rather a matter of the values equaling `0` because of the increment operator `c++` used instead of `++c`.

```
int a=0, b=0, c=0;
cout<<"a:"<<a<<'\n'<<"b:"<<b<<'\n'<<"c:"<<c<<"\n\n";
// output is 
// a:0
// b:0
// c:0
a = ++b,++c;
cout<<"a:"<<a<<'\n'<<"b:"<<b<<'\n'<<"c:"<<c<<"\n\n";
// output is 
// a:1
// b:1
// c:1
```

Comment: `=` has a higher precedence than `,`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Thank you very much. Suppose it is best to consider precedence when using operators.

Comment: The value of both `b++` and `c++` is `0`.

Comment: @molbdnilo You are correct, because of operator precedence as noted by  Richard Critten. The course I was taking sure didn't explain that. So, -1 to them, and +1 to Richard.

Comment: @envisisoft I think you're missing my point. Precedence has no visible effect on the result in this example – if you write just `a = c++;`, `a`  will also be `0`.

Comment: @molbdnilo I see what you mean. If i assign `++c` to `a`, then it increments by 1.